# Computing Altitude Azimuth from device orientation (alpha, beta, gamma)

Tags: javascript, three.js, device-orientation, altitude, azimuth

I'm editing an exsisting web application which only support input [ra,dec] = [altitude,azimuth], I am able to get the alpha, beta, gamma angles from device orientation events (link bellow)

https://www.sitepoint.com/using-device-orientation-html5/

The image bellow describes the altitude and azimuth I am trying to compute :

https://www.heavens-above.com/images/azel.gif

the eye is the back of the phone.

The altitude changes with Beta and Gamma changes

The azimuth depend on all 3 angles (I guess).

I expect the output to be two angles, altitude one and the azimuth one.

Comment: Perhaps you can use `THREE.DeviceOrientationControls`. https://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_deviceorientation.html. If not, you can study the code.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to mention it, I've tried it, it works but I can't get the azimuth out of it nor the altitude,  the azimuth and altitude are given by the OrbitControls, https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/controls/OrbitControls but I wasn't able convert.